# Admob Implementation with iPad Multitasking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I am trying to implement an Admob banner into an app with multitasking enabled but I get this error:

```
<Google> Invalid Request. The GADRequest scene property should be set for
applications that support multi-scene. Treating the unset property as an error
while in test mode.
```

If anyone knows how to successfully implement an Admob banner in multitasking app, please help me

I have a problem with writing code for viewDidApper function.

Code that I already have:

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

func loadInterstitial() {
   let request = GADRequest()
   request.scene = view.window?.windowScene
   interstitial.load(request)
}

func loadBannerAd() {
   let bannerWidth = view.frame.size.width

   bannerView.adSize = GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(bannerWidth)

   let request = GADRequest()
   request.scene = view.window?.windowScene
   bannerView.load(request)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
   coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { context in
       self.loadBannerAd()
   }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

   addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
   bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
   bannerView.rootViewController = self
   bannerView.load(GADRequest())
   bannerView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share some code what you have already tried, using a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: Did you read this: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/multiscene ?

Comment: koen, thank you! I added the code which I have for a banner. I've read that guide but I didn't get what to write in viewDidAppear so I guess that's why the code I provided doesn't work

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Searching the docs is always a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! Tho I still haven't figured out what to write in viewDidAppear because the Admob guide doesn't provide where and when to implement requestInitialized variable..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in `viewDidAppear()`? You don't have to use it.

Comment: According to the guide I need to build an ad request in viewDidAppear with this code (objc) : `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  if (!_requestInitialized) {
    [self loadInterstitial];
    _requestInitialized = YES;
  }
} `  Without that, I get the same error

Comment: They provide you the code, so what is your question? Also, can you edit your title, it has nothing to do with iPad multitasking.

Comment: The question is what is `requestInitialized` ? The title is like that because the error I get is caused by the fact that iPad multitasking is enabled

Comment: Looks like it is a bool variable, just add that to your properties and give it an initial value of false.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but I was still getting an error. Anyways, I just deleted all the code from the `viewDidAppear` and ran my app on a physical device and everything works just fine! So, I guess that's a bug with simulators... thank you so much for your help anyways!

Comment: Sure. I noticed you posted a very similar question earlier today. Please keep one subject per question.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I just reposted because I didn't get an answer..

Answer (score 6):

You should add the `scene` to `GADRequest`

Here an example:

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
```